# Rails routes filter by categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, routes, categories

I have two models in my app:

```
class Suggest < ActiveRecord::Base
   belong_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :suggests
end
```

I would like to make a routes:

**/suggests/category1/**  --list all suggests from Category 1

**/suggests/category2/**  --list all suggests from Category 2

**/suggests/category1/123**  //show suggest from Category 1 of ID 123

**/suggests/category1/123/edit**  //edit suggest from Category 1 of ID 123

How I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it kinda the wrong way;

Since your category has many suggests, to list all suggests (suggestions!?) from a single category, you should have a route:

`/category1/suggests` and not the other way around:

To make it like that you should do:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :suggests
end
```

That way you will get routes:

> /category1/suggests --list all suggests from Category 1
>
> /category2/suggests --list all suggests from Category 2
>
> /category1/suggests/123 //show suggest from Category 1 of ID
>
> /category1/suggests/123/edit //edit suggest from Category 1 of ID 123

Comment: Sorry, but this way I will have: 'categories/:id/suggests' and I need 'suggests/:category_name/'.